# How to sign file with non-exportable certificate in powershell?

Tags: powershell, certificate, root, sign

I try to use this code in PowerShell:

```
$path = 'cert:\currentuser\my\' + 'Thumbprint_My_Certificate'
$cert=Get-ChildItem -Path $path
$choicec=$cert | Where-Object HasPrivateKey -eq 'true' | Where-Object { $_.Subject -eq "CN=CN_Name_My_Certificate" }
 Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\TestFilePS.txt -Certificate $choicec*
```

In that case I have this error:

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Certificate' because it is null.
At line:1 char:94
+ ... ath C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\TestFilePS.txt -Certificate $choicec
+                                                                  ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-AuthenticodeSignature], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAuthenti
   codeSignatureCommand*
```

When I changed last command to

Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\TestFilePS.txt -Certificate **$cert**

I have this error:

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature : Cannot sign code. The specified certificate is not suitable for code signing.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\Test ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AuthenticodeSignature], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAuthenticodeSignatureCommand
```

The output of $cert | fl * is as follows:

```
PSPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::currentuser\my\XXXThumbprint_My_CertificateXXX
PSParentPath             : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::currentuser\my
PSChildName              : XXXThumbprint_My_CertificateXXX
PSDrive                  : Cert
PSProvider               : Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate
PSIsContainer            : False
EnhancedKeyUsageList     : {Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1), Client Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2)}
DnsNameList              : {MyComputerName, MyDomain}
SendAsTrustedIssuer      : False
EnrollmentPolicyEndPoint : Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.EnrollmentEndPointProperty
EnrollmentServerEndPoint : Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.EnrollmentEndPointProperty
PolicyId                 : 
Archived                 : False
Extensions               : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid...}
FriendlyName             : 
IssuerName               : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
NotAfter                 : 09.05.2023 23:13:07
NotBefore                : 09.05.2021 23:13:07
HasPrivateKey            : True
PrivateKey               : System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
PublicKey                : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey
RawData                  : {48, 130, 6, 249...}
SerialNumber             : XXXSerial_Number_My_CertificateXX
SubjectName              : System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName
SignatureAlgorithm       : System.Security.Cryptography.Oid
Thumbprint               : XXXThumbprint_My_CertificateXXX
Version                  : 3
Handle                   : 2049462886560
Issuer                   : CN=CN_Name_My_Certificate, O=CompanyName
Subject                  : CN=CN_Name_My_Certificate, OU=OU_Name, O=CompanyName, L=L_Name
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You dont use a root certificate to sign code. Suggest you read up on it. You should have a personal certificate signed by your CA with authority to sign code and use that.

Comment: To expand on @Scepticalist, assuming you have a Windows Certificate Authority, you connect to the CA, launch the Certificate Authority Console / app, then request a new cert with `Code Signature` extensions, as described here: https://community.flexera.com/t5/Software-Vulnerability-Manager/Creating-Windows-CA-Code-Signing-Certificate-for-WSUS/ta-p/149698

Comment: Sorry, you are right this is not  a root certificate. It is a personal certificate signed by our CA. How can I check authority to sign code in Powershell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have requested the certifcate and it has been added to the Domain group policy "Trusted Publishers" section properly the process of signing itself is fairly easy. The PowerShell command follows the below syntax –

```
Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath LOCATIONOFSCRIPT -Certificate LOCATIONOFCERT –TimestampServer TSASERVER
```

Where –

LOCATIONOFSCRIPT = Path to the script to be signed

LOCATIONOFCERT = Path to your user certificate

TSASERVER = An external Time Stamp Authority that allows the script to continue to be trusted after the certificate used to sign it has expired

So, as follows, assuming the certificate is correctly located in your personal store:

```
$cert=(dir cert:currentuser\my\ -CodeSigningCert)

$script = 'C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\TestFilePS.txt'

# Alternative timestamp sources:
#http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode
#http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll
#http://tsa.starfieldtech.com
#
Try {
    Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath $($script) -Certificate $cert -TimestampServer http://timestamp.digicert.com -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop

}
Catch { 
    $_
}
```

Comment: I think that this method using for sign of script with extension "ps1", but I need to sign a file. I have a task - sign and encrypt file with SMIME. For signing i want to use powershell, because I don't know how to use non-exportable certificate in openssl, for encryption I will use openssl.

Comment: When I use this method I getting this message: PS $path = 'cert:\myuser\my\' + 'Thumbprint_My_Certificate' PS $cert=Get-ChildItem -Path $path PS C:\Users\myuser> Set-AuthenticodeSignature -FilePath C:\Users\myuser\TestFilePS.txt -Certificate $cert –TimestampServer "time.windows.com" Set-AuthenticodeSignature : Cannot sign code. The specified certificate is not suitable for code signing.

Comment: You can sign any type of file, not just a ps1. That error obviously means you dont have a code signing certificate. See @FoxDeploy comments on your above post to make one.

Comment: Thanks all! I sent this topic to our IT team with your comments.